# Docker-compose for mysql, phpmyadmin and nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I want to use a dockerized SQL database server, an additional client (here: phpmyadmin) and a reverse proxy to make the client interface reachable from outside servers.

So far I used this docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
        mariatest:
                image: mysql
                restart: always
                networks:
                       - dbnet
                environment:
                        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
                        MYSQL_DATABASE: test
                        MYSQL_USER: test
                        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test

        phpmatest:
                depends_on:
                        - mariatest
                image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
                restart: always
                networks:
                        - dbnet
                ports:
                        - "9080:80"
                environment:
                        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
                        PMA_HOST: mariatest

        reverse:
                image: nginx
                networks:
                        - dbnet
                ports:
                        - "8000:80"
                volumes:
                        - /var/dockervolumes/nginx:/etc/nginx

networks:
     dbnet:
```

The taken from the volume I get the nginx default.conf file as

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9080/;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

When using the local machine with http://localhost:9080 I can use the PMA without any problems. When trying to use the reverse proxy address (http://localhost:8000) I only get an nginx error the page I am looking for is unavailable. Inside the logs I see that the reverse proxy fails on the connect() with connection refused.

What am I missing for such setups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely because localhost is container-based.  Have you tried putting in your host's ip address, eg:

```
proxy_pass http://[HOSTIP]:9080/;
```

You may need to either static your container IPs or request them by their hostname.  To use DNS, set the container host name (one way is to set container_name), eg:

```
services:
    phpmatest:
        container_name: phpmatest
```

and in nginx conf file:

```
proxy_pass http://phpmatest:80/;
```

should work because they are on the same container network.

You will need to also set up nginx to receive DNS from docker, in case a container needs to restart or change.  There are tutorials on how to do this elsewhere.

Comment: I added the container name and the nginx conf for the container name - after restarts, the nginx handles the name in the url, but fails with "connection refused" while connecting to upstream

Comment: have you tested connectivity from inside your nginx container? ```curl phpmatest:80```

Comment: ok, I found my misunderstanding. I thought, the nginx has to target the exposed port, but phpmatest:80 is correct as it connects via the dbnet network directy. Thank you for the clarification and help!

Comment: @R.StackUser I'm late to the party but I have a near identical problem. I have tried to connect directly with curl, and I am getting connection refused. This is in my local dev environment as well.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues with your code :

**First :-**

`/var/dockervolumes/nginx:/etc/nginx` 
This doesn't let nginx start inside container because nginx configuration doesn't get auto-created due to volume binding.

Try using `docker ps` command to verify.

Using `/var/dockervolumes/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d` works

I am assuming you will place your **default.conf** file inside **conf.d** folder

> Note: If you bind any directory inside container to host system,
>   that directory is not initialised by container.

**Second :-**

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:9080/;
```

You assuming that localhost inside your container and you real host is same.

Use `proxy_pass http://phpmatest;` that will work because your service name is **phpmatest**

> Note: If you create a customer docker network i.e **dbtest** in your case. All services using same network are directly accessible by their name i.e phpmatest in your case.

**Following works :-**

**docker-compose file**

```
version: '3'

services:
        mariatest:
                image: mysql
                restart: always
                networks:
                       - dbnet
                environment:
                        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
                        MYSQL_DATABASE: test
                        MYSQL_USER: test
                        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test

        phpmatest:
                depends_on:
                        - mariatest
                image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
                restart: always
                networks:
                        - dbnet
                ports:
                        - "9080:80"
                environment:
                        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
                        PMA_HOST: mariatest

        reverse:
                image: nginx
                networks:
                        - dbnet
                ports:
                        - "8000:80"
                volumes:
                        - /var/dockervolumes/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d

networks:
     dbnet:
```

**default.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://phpmatest;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: default.conf works fine. i was running phpmyadmin on a random port &  proxy_pass http://localhost:PORT;